# Trying to use jQuery-UI drag-and-drop or double-click to clone from non-sortable to sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, clone

I am trying to combine several solutions I have found - mostly using answers found here on stackoverflow - thank you very much.

I am trying to create a drag-and-drop solution using jquery-ui. I have a list of items in  that I want to add to . I have my requirements:

1. when I drag an item from "choices" it should NOT be removed from the list. I am using the clone() method to accomplish this.
2. I want to be able to select where in "selections" the item gets dropped. I have accomplished this by using .sortable()
3. I want to be able to re-order items within the "selections" list
4. If I double-click an item from the "choices", I would like it to be automatically added to the bottom of the "selections" list.
5. When the item gets added to the "selections" list, I need to change the effect of double-click.

My current solution can be seen with this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q0k7ouud/

```
<div id="items-selector">

  <ul id="choices" class="window-view">
    <li class="boilerplate-li" id="bp-1">item-1</li>
    <li class="boilerplate-li" id="bp-2">item-2</li>
    <li class="boilerplate-li" id="bp-3">item-3</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="selections" class="window-view">
  </ul>

</div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#items-selector #choices').sortable({
    connectWith: '#items-selector #selections',
    forcePlaceholderSize: false,
    helper: function(e, li) {
      copyHelper = li.clone().insertAfter(li);
      return li.clone();
    },
    stop: function() {
      copyHelper && copyHelper.remove();
    },
    containment: '#items-selector'
  });
  $("#items-selector #selections").sortable({
    receive: function(e, ui) {
      copyHelper = null;
    }
  });
});
```

Here are the issues which I am hoping stackoverflow can help me, please:

1. I do NOT want to be able to rearrange items within the "choices" .
2. When I begin to drag an item, the clone is inserted into the "choices" list causing the list to jump down, but then the list jumps back up as I continue to drag the item.
3. I do not know how to add the double-click functionality (requirements 4 and 5 above). As for #4, I suspect I can use a simple ondblclick attribute, but I am not sure how I change this attribute once it gets added to the "selections" list.

For these issues, I have attempted to replace sortable() with draggable() and dropable(), tweaking the helper: functions, and other insights I have tried to extract from other people's questions. But it seemed that if I fixed one issue, I created another, until I ended up chasing my tail. I am hoping the experts on stackoverflow might help direct me to a complete solution.

I thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: A lot of these ID selectors do not match up with the HTML. I would also make `choices` a list of draggable items instead of a sortable. This will ensure they cannot be sorted. Also draggable can handle helpers better and will allow you to better clone the dragged item into the sortable. You can bind the doubleclick callback to the list of `choices` and when you append the "clone" to `selections`, it would not have the callback anymore.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did not have matching ID selectors in my sample. I have updated my sample accordingly. I will see what I can do with your suggestions. I have worked with sortable lists and draggable/droppable lists, but I did not try combining the two.

Answer (score 0):

@Twisty Put me on the right path. What I needed was to use .draggable() for my choices. The key was the connectToSortable key which allowed me to connect the draggable-items to the sortable-list. I still have not implemented the double-click functionality I described in my original question, but now that the dust has settled on this drag and drop, that should be pretty straight forward.

Here is the new javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#items-selector #choices li').draggable({
    connectToSortable: '#items-selector #selections',
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    scope: "drop",
    containment: '#items-selector'
  });
  $("#items-selector #selections").sortable({
    receive: function(e, ui) {
      copyHelper = null;
    }
  });
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q0k7ouud/5/